# GNU make doesn't execute command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two different OS environment: CentOS6 and CentOS7.

The CentOS6 GNU make version is 3.81

The CentOS7 GNU make version is 3.82

My Makefile is below

```
%o : %c   
    $(CC) -c $(CPFLAGS) -I. $(INCDIR) $< -o $@
```

3.81 works very well.

But 3.82 will NOT execute the cmmand

```
$(CC) -c $(CPFLAGS) -I. $(INCDIR) $< -o $@
```

It seems ONLY execute its default command

```
%o : %c
```

What i see on the terminal, will expand like this ===> gcc c -o main.o main.c

After some test, I'm sure that this line
$(CC) -c $(CPFLAGS) -I. $(INCDIR) $< -o $@
will NEVER be executed.

After searching by Google, I rewrite in another syntax format

```
.c.o:

    $(CC) -c $(CPFLAGS) -I. $(INCDIR) $< -o $@
```

This works!!
$(CC) -c $(CPFLAGS) -I. $(INCDIR) $< -o $@
will execute!!!

I read the 3.82 release note and doesn't get any clue about this problem.

Could you help me to explain why?

I don't think this is caused by different GNU make version.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

> It seems ONLY execute its default command
>
> `%o : %c`

that is not correct.  The default rule for building an object file from a C source file is not `%o : %c`, it is `%.o : %.c`.  The difference here (the added `.`) may seem small but it is the reason for the behavior you see.

Since the default rule is `%.o : %.c`, when you define your own rule using `%o : %c` that is a completely different rule: it does not *replace* the existing rule, it is a new rule *in addition to* the existing rule.

So now there are *two* pattern rules that can be used to build an object file from a C source file.  How does make decide which one to use?  The algorithm for choosing changed between GNU Make 3.81 and GNU Make 3.82.

In GNU Make 3.81 and earlier, the *first defined rule* was always chosen (where default rules are considered to be define last).  That means that your rule `%o: %c` was chosen.

In GNU Make 3.82 and later, the *best match* is always chosen.  The best match is define as the rule where the *stem* (the part that matches the `%`) is the shortest (our put alternatively, the most specific rule is chosen).  If we want to build `foo.o` from `foo.c`, then in the default rule the stem is `foo` and in your alternative rule the default is `foo.` (for a pattern `%o` matching the string `foo.o` the stem--the part matching `%`--is `foo.`).

Since the stem of the built-in rule is shorter (`foo` is 3 characters long) than the stem of your pattern rule (`foo.` is four characters long), the built-in rule is *more specific* and so it will be chosen.

If you want your makefile to work with all versions then instead of creating an *extra* rule you should *replace* the built in rule by using the *same* patterns, not different patterns; write your rule as:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CPFLAGS) -I. $(INCDIR) $< -o $@
```

and it will work with all versions of GNU Make.

Your rule is not great anyway since by leaving out the `.` it means that rule would match any target file that ended with `o` (not just `.o`) and any prerequisite that ended with `c` (not just `.c`).

Comment: oh you are right, I didn't find this tiny difference when reading release note. Thanks!!! This is so helpful for my team!!!